# How to create python GUI apps that control and displaying data from Python-OSC Server?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing, osc

I am beginner in python. I want to create Python GUI application that control OSC Server (start and stop) and displaying the data into window. The problem is, when I run OSC Server the window did't show up until PSC Server finishes itself. And the function that supposed to change the data within global variable failed to changed.

```
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from pythonosc.osc_server import AsyncIOOSCUDPServer
from pythonosc.dispatcher import Dispatcher
import asyncio

ip = "0.0.0.0"
port = 5000
koneksi=None
def filter_handler(address, *args):
    # print(f"{address}: {args}")
    for arg in args:
        status(arg)
        
def status(stat):
    global koneksi
    if stat==1:
        koneksi="Connected"
    else:
        koneksi="Disconnected"
    # print(koneksi)
    
    

dispatcher = Dispatcher()
dispatcher.map("/muse/elements/touching_forehead", filter_handler)



async def loop():
    """Example main loop that only runs for 10 iterations before finishing"""
    for i in range(2):
        print(f"Loop {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def init_main():
    server = AsyncIOOSCUDPServer((ip, port), dispatcher, asyncio.get_event_loop())
    transport, protocol = await server.create_serve_endpoint()  # Create datagram endpoint and start serving
    await loop()  # Enter main loop of program
    transport.close()  # Clean up serve endpoint
        
def tombol_click():
    asyncio.run(init_main())

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x400")
window.resizable(False,False)
frame=ttk.Frame(window)
labelDevice=ttk.Label(frame,text="Device :")
labelDevice.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10,pady=10)

labelStatus=ttk.Label(frame,text=koneksi)
labelStatus.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=10,pady=10)
tombol_sapa = ttk.Button(frame,text="start",command=tombol_click())
tombol_sapa.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10, pady=10)



frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to search similar problem but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `threading`. First, we launch a single-threaded `tkinter` and from it we launch a thread to work with the `OSC server`.

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk


# Create a window with a button and a label.
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = tk.Button(self, command=self.start_action, text="start")
        self.button.pack(padx=100, pady=50)
        self.lable = tk.Label(self, text="initial value")
        self.lable.pack(padx=100, pady=50)

# We start an additional thread for the PSC Server.
    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.init_main)
        thread.start()
        self.check_thread(thread)

# We make the button active only after the flow is completed.
    def check_thread(self, thread):
        if thread.is_alive():
            self.check = self.after(500, lambda: self.check_thread(thread))
        else:
            self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def init_main(self):
        # start dispatcher,server
        self.loop()  # Enter main loop of program
        # Clean up serve endpoint

    def loop(self):
        """Example main loop that only runs for 10 iterations before finishing"""
        for i in range(2):
            print(f"Loop {i}")
            self.lable.config(text=f"Loop {i}")
            time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I took the basis for the program from [here](https://pythonru.com/uroki/asinhronnoe-prilozhenie-ch-1-tkinter-15#:%7E:text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0.-,%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85,-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA).